# Word that includes clothes and shoes?

Tags: single-word-requests

Basically, I'm looking for a word for "wearables". Example:

Mary put on the __ she wasn't wearing yet: panties, pants, pumps.

Maybe *accessories*?

Comment: accessories would be more like jewellery, handbags...

Comment: Mary put on the rest of her garments (or attire);...It's self-evident that she wasn't wearing them yet, so no need to include that bit. ;)

Answer (score -1):

If one wants to include all garments at one's disposal, whether they are are in one's closet or luggage or are being worn, "wardrobe" would be appropriate.

definition of wardrobe
2
a :  a collection of wearing apparel (as of one person or for one activity)

© 2017 Merriam-Webster, Incorporated

Comment: 'Basically, I'm looking for a word for "wearables". Example:

Mary put on the wardrobe she wasn't wearing yet: panties, pants, pumps.'?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth \ Ah yes! I remember you from question 184754; and, remembering you, I shall not waste further time on this.